# How to fix the growing nodset with xpath, memory allocation failed

Tags: xpath, ubuntu-20.04, xmllint, xml-libxml, node-set

I am using **xmllint** to fetch some data from xml file, by using following command:

`xmllint --xpath '//Module[TestCase/Test[@result="fail"]]/@name' test.xml`

The same command worked for some time, but triggering it few time, I am getting an error as

> XPath error : Memory allocation failed : growing nodeset hit limit
>
> growing nodeset hit limit
>
> ^
> XPath evaluation failure

**Please note:** The `xmllint --xpath '//Module[TestCase/Test[@result="fail"]]/@name' test.xml` command is working fine when I using the test.xml whose size is **1MB**, but when the use the same command with test.xml whose size is **390MB** then I am facing the issue

I tried troubleshooting by trying to increase the xpath nodeset length XPATH_MAX_NODESET_LENGTH 90000000 and `export XPATH_MAX_NODESET_LENGTH 90000000` but it dint helped me.

Comment: Have you tried `xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//Module[TestCase/Test[@result="fail"]]/@name' test.xml`  ?

Comment: Hi @GillesQuénot , Yeah I have tried with `xmlstarlet` too, I got the similar error:
**Memory allocation failed : growing nodeset hit limit**

Comment: or `xidel -e '//Module[TestCase/Test[@result="fail"]]/@name' -s test.xml`

Comment: If it doesn't work, do this on a box with more RAM =)

Comment: Thats a typo while asking the question, but I have given the  `=` in my export

Comment: Try `xmllint --huge ...`

Answer (score 1):

A file size of 390Mb should be possible these days if you configure enough memory, but it's pushing it.

You could try downloading Saxon and using the XQuery command line interface:

```
java net.sf.saxon.Query -s:test.xml 
  -qs:"//Module[TestCase/Test[@result='fail']]/@name
```

If necessary, you could get a license for Saxon-EE and run this in streaming mode, which would definitely solve the memory problems.

Comment: Does default XQuery serialization work with queries returning a sequence of attribute nodes? Probably safer to use `//Module[TestCase/Test[@result='fail']]/@name/string()`, whether with streaming or not.